# java requestmapping returns 404 error with Postman

Tags: java, postman

Im trying to have java respond to a GET request from Postman.  When I use Postman to send a GET request to localhost:8080/chat this is the response (I had expected to get an empty list returned as there is no data present yet:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-04-02T20:00:26.413+0000",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/chat"
}
```

I have 2 packages in my application.  They are com.dogo and com.dogochat.chat.  The file in com.dogo is DogoApplication.java.  This is the code:

```
package com.dogo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DogoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DogoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

The second package is called com.dogochat.chat.  There are 3 files (2 classes and 1 interface).  The file names are Message.java, MessageController.java, and MessageRepository.java.

This is the code in Message.java:

```
package com.dogochat.chat;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="message")
public class Message {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String content;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }    
    }
```

This is the code in MessageController.java:

```
package com.dogochat.chat;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/chat")
public class MessageController {

    @Autowired
    MessageRepository dao;

    @GetMapping("/get")
    public List<Message> getMessages(){
        List<Message> foundMessages = dao.findAll();
        return foundMessages;
    }

    @PostMapping("/post")
    public ResponseEntity<Message> postMessage(@RequestBody Message message) 
    {
        // saving to DB using instance of the repo interface
        Message createdMessage = dao.save(message);
        // RespEntity crafts response to include correct status codes.
        return ResponseEntity.ok(createdMessage);
    }
}
```

This is the code in MessageRepository.java (although I dont think this is needed for this small test)

```
package com.dogochat.chat;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface MessageRepository extends JpaRepository<Message, Integer>{

}
```

Any help/suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't @RequestMapping have a method property provided? e.g. @RequestMapping(path = "/chat", method = Request method.GET)

Comment: My code now reads like this:     @RequestMapping(path = "/chat", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Message> getMessages(){
        List<Message> foundMessages = dao.findAll();
        return foundMessages;
    }   but I still get the same 404 error

Comment: With the updated code, I think the 404 maybe because you are using get with spring data, i.e. object not found, not URL not working. If you add data and then call the get end point, does it still return 404?

Comment: I removed the @RequestMapping("/chat") that was after the @RestController and that seems to have resolved my issue.  Thanks for your time and assistance

Answer (score 1):

I know I am pretty late for the response, but better late than never.

This is a very common mistake for new Spring boot developers and I have also faced this issue several times.

The reason for this is the package under which you have your **main()** method.

In your case your **MessageController, Message** and your **MessageRepository** is under the package `com.dogochat.chat`, but then your **main()** method is under `com.dogo` which is completely a different package.

**@SpringBootApplication** internally runs **@ComponentScan** and if parent package and child packages are different, it cannot run and scan and throws the above error.

To avoid this confusion, follow this package structure.

[image]

Hope this helps. Happy coding !

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if your `@SpringBootApplication` class is on top of all your packages or at least in the same package. It seems like your URL path is not visible.

Also, in your PostMan, you have to configure your `headers` the `content-type=application/json`.

For a more readable code (just my point of view), you should have something like this :

```
package com.dogochat.chat;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/chat")
public class MessageController {

    @Autowired
    MessageRepository dao;

    @GetMapping("/get")
    public List<Message> getMessages(){
        List<Message> foundMessages = dao.findAll();
        return foundMessages;
    }

    @PostMapping("/post")
    public ResponseEntity<Message> postMessage(@RequestBody Message message) 
    {
        // saving to DB using instance of the repo interface
        Message createdMessage = dao.save(message);
        // RespEntity crafts response to include correct status codes.
        return ResponseEntity.ok(createdMessage);
    }
}
```

Comment: @SpringBootApplication is at the top of one of my packages.  I have 2 packages in the src/main/java folder.  The first is called com.dogo which contains the file DogoApplication.java.  The second package is called com.dogochat.chat and that contains 3 files, Message.java, MessageController.java, and MessageRepository.java.  I have edited my original question to contain the code of all 4 files.

Comment: As your Controller changed a little bit your new path should be : localhost:8080/chat/get, if you want to call the getMessages() method.

Comment: I removed the @RequestMapping("/chat") that was after the @RestController and that seems to have resolved my issue. Thanks for your time and assistance